# Close duplicates only when the original was answered, and redirect future viewers to that original automatically

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

I suggest that when someone finds an exact duplicate of a question he/she should do the following:

In case that original question was solved (an answer was accepted by the author of the question), this new duplicate should have a field (e.g. "duplicate_of") and the server will redirect automatically to that original answered question.

If the original question was *not* answered, even though this question is duplicate, it is actually a real world unsolved problem that yet another person has come across.

When someone googles for something and the results says "foo bar baz [closed]", he or she then needs to read through the comments and answers in order to find how to get to the other question. That is a waste of time! Why not let the site take them directly to the answer (and probably indicate redirection on the landing page as well).

Comment: There is a direct link to the dupe in the header, after the question was closed.

Comment: This is a two-part suggestion: I agree heartily with the "redirect" part, and disagree completely with the "unanswered == not duplicate" part. Some users never accept answers, but that doesn't mean the answers aren't good, comprehensive, and worth referencing instead of duplicating.